# Pharo Smalltalk - Is it possible to assign super to some other instance after the Object has been instantiated?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, amber-smalltalk

Suppose we have `oneInstance` and `secondInstance`, one of `SomeClass` and one `OtherClass` with the example Class hierarchy below:

```
oneInstance
Object
 - SomeClass (some variables of it's own, nothing major)

secondInstance
Object
 - SomethingClass
 - OtherClass (just about any class in the tree here)
```

Is it possible, at runtime, to change oneInstance so that it's "super" message sends reach secondInstance.

oneInstance and secondInstance *merge* essentially making oneInstance  work as if they are one object and the structure appear as if they were instantiated from something like and:

```
secondInstance wraps around oneInstance
    Object
     - SomethingClass
     - OtherClass (just about any class in the tree here)
     - SomeClass (some variables of it's own, nothing major)
```

The simplest would be if I could assign `super := secondInstance` on oneInstance for a bit and then change it back `:D`

PS. Essentially we are reclassing oneInstance by having secondInstance as it's "super" they are now one object with the state of both presuming oneInstance is subclassed from Object with no other state but it's own. Mostly a hack to use the inheritance chain's default method lookup to my advantage. Closest thing I could find is Object Slicing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing

Another way to look at it would be this:

secondInstance is receiving messages, it's an instance of OtherClass, all is well. Some of the messages it receives are not in OtherClass so method lookup goes up the inheritance chain to SomethingClass and then to Object, ProtoObject, etc. and finally they should be forwarded to the other instance. This process should be entirely transparent.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to do mixins.
There are some implementations of that for Squeak/Pharo.
May be you should look that way.
Personally, I find this a bad idea and would take a redesign instead of trying to tamper single inheritance or method lookup.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It sounds like either the Strategy Pattern or State Pattern: "`The object will appear to change its class.`" https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state

Comment: @quamrana Wow that looks remarkably similar to what I'm trying to do, one detail though: Does this pattern allow for the instance to be in multiple "states" at the same time, that is be part of multiple ***nested** contexts* at the same time? Or is the "state" change atomic once it goes into a "state" that context execution must end before another context can have it perform?

Comment: Its much cleaner if you keep to one state at a time. Typically a client of your instance invokes a series methods within the same state, then a change of state occurs at the end of one method upon a defined condition. The client then invokes more methods from the new state, maybe unaware of the change. Technically there is nothing stopping you from changing state whilst in a method and from there calling more methods, which can in turn change the state etc.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia I'm looking for a way to define behaviour that is context specific. I instantiate the context and then three or four of these objects that only have behaviour attached to them. They should be able to wrap around the players of these roles, which have no awareness of the context of their own, they only receive messages from it via the roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in Pharo and Squeak (and most Smalltalks) you are **always** at runtime. So obviously, if its possible to do something, its possible to do it at "runtime". :)

Generally messing around with meta capabilities for "regular code" leads to really deceptive code that is hard to debug, both for you and especially others. So to implement #doesNotUnderstand: and using #respondsTo: etc, is normally "bad style" unless you REALLY have to do these things.

An obvious example for transparent forwarder objects is proxies for OODBS - but there really aren't many good examples.

But to answer more precisely - in your implementation of #doesNotUnderstand: - just query if `self respondsTo: aMessage selector` (or similar) and make your decision to delegate or not based on that.

Comment: True. By "runtime" I meant after the Object has been instantiated. Modified the question to reflect this.